# Python, making a variable defined in a "slightly more global" scope

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, global

Let's consider the following script:

```
def a():
   def b():
      smth = 3
   print smth
```

**Is there any way to make the object smth defined not in the global scope, but in the scope of the a() function although we create it inside the b() function ?**

Something like:

```
def a():
   def b():
      smth = 3
      a_bit_more_global smth
   print smth
```

The reason is the following:

```
class Blabla(object):
   def __init__(self,q,w)
     self.q = q
     self.w=w
def a():
   def b():
      smth_2 = smth_1 + 1
      global smth_2
   smth_1 = 2
   fen1 = Tk()
   ...
   ...
   Button(...,command=b).grid()
   my_blabla = Blabla(smth_1,smth_2)
   return my_blabla
```

I first didn't know how to pass extra argument to the function b(). I finally thought I could put b() inside a(). And then, same problem, I want to use an object created in b() in order to create the object my_blabla. How would you deal with this issue ?

I hope my explainations make sense ! do they ?

Thank you !

Comment: It's 'scope'. And no, not like that, not in Python 2.

Comment: Global variables (or even what you're suggesting) usually isn't such good coding practice, python prefers you pass everything around through parameters and returns. Is there any reason why this would not be possible for your script? Perhaps there's another solution

Comment: I updated my post after Josh comment. Thks

Comment: What are you expecting `smth.1` to do?

Comment: That was supposed to be just a name. Please forgive the beginner I am ;)

Comment: If you put both functions inside of your class, you could store smth_2 in the instance so that you could do self.smth_2 = smth_1 + 1. That seems like the simplest most "Pythonic" way to go about it in this scenario.

Comment: Great ! you're right here the solution I needed. Thanks a lot. Do you want to write it as an answer ? Sorry that I brought some missunderstanding with my question !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Josh said:

Deplace the functions inside the class and store smth_2 as self.smth_2

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a return statement e.g.

```
def a():
   def b():
      smth = 3
      return smth
   smth = b()
   print smth
```

Comment: `b` is passed as `command` parameter to `Button`. Its return value is unavailable. [`self.smth` inside a method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17842619/4279) could be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not in python.  You could something LIKE it with the following

```
def a():
   smth = []
   def b():
      smth = 3
   if smth != []:   
      print smth
```

I caution strongly against this because you open up a wide array of potential bugs that would be difficult to fix.  I would recommend your `b()` function return anything that it creates that you would need elsewhere

```
def b():
    smth = 3
    return smth
```

If you ABSOLUTELY must do something like this I'd consider another language like C++ where you could allocate `smth` dynamically

Comment: In Python 3 you could use `nonlocal`.

Answer (score 0):

An example is equal to a thousand answers:

```
def a():
   def b():
      smth = 3
      return smth
   smth = b()
   print smth
```